# Android application development

Tags: android, air

I read recently in a magazine that it's now possible to write / use Adobe-Air applications on android devices.

I've been developing android applications for 3 months and find that it's sometimes tricky to get the desired results using android sdk.

On the other hand I read that you can use html and javascript stuff in AIR applications.

So the question: Who here has developed with both AIR and the Android SDK: which way is more elegant, better for performance or easier?!

Thank you,

Mur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention using html and javascript in your application...check out [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/)

I've used it for small applications only so far, but it is a very cool way to develop mobile apps.